# addTarget for UIButton in TableViewCell doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm making a table view app, and have created UITableViewCell programmatically. The cell consists of 2 views, the first one for the Label, and the second one is for 2 buttons and label. Pressing on the button should change the label's title. Also, I'm using delegates to implement logic in the view controller. 
Here is my cell code. Sorry for the mess with the constraints. I'm only learning to implement them nicely.

```
protocol FinalCellDelegate {
    func addButtonPressed(sender: UIButton)
    func subtactButtonPressed(sender: UIButton)
}


class FinalCell: UITableViewCell {
  let label = UILabel()
  var addButton = UIButton()
  var numberLabel = UILabel()
  var subtractButton = UIButton()
  var delegate: FinalCellDelegate?


  override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()

   }

   override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: "FinalCell")


        contentView.addSubview(label)
        let addAndSubtractView = UIView()
        addAndSubtractView.addSubview(addButton)
        addAndSubtractView.addSubview(numberLabel)
        addAndSubtractView.addSubview(subtractButton)
        contentView.addSubview(addAndSubtractView)

        //constraints
        addButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addAndSubtractView.trailingAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
        addButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: numberLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        addButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        subtractButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        subtractButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: addAndSubtractView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        subtractButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: numberLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        subtractButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        numberLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        numberLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        addAndSubtractView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addAndSubtractView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        addAndSubtractView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true


        label.textColor = .black
        subtractButton.setTitle("-", for: .normal)
        subtractButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        addButton.setTitle("+", for: .normal)
        addButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        numberLabel.text = "0"
        numberLabel.textColor = .black

        subtractButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(subtractButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

  @objc func addButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
      print("addButtonTapped")
       delegate?.addButtonPressed(sender: sender)
   }

   @objc func subtractButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
       print("subtractButtonTapped")
       delegate?.subtactButtonPressed(sender: sender)
   }

   }
```

Here is my cellForRow at indexPath code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FinalCell", for: indexPath) as! FinalCell
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.cellTag = indexPath.row
        cell.addButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.subtractButton.tag = indexPath.row

        return cell
    }
```

And of course delegate implementation :

```
extension FinalGameSettings: FinalCellDelegate {

    func addButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        print("works")
    }
    func subtactButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        print("This works too")
}
}
```

The problem is, that when I press on Button - nothing happens. Please, give me a piece of advice to handle the problem!

Comment: what do you mean nothing happens, you mean delegate does not work or button does not trigger action? 
which text is appearing after clicking on buttons in the console log?

Comment: I've added print statements in both ViewController and TableViewCell to check where is the problem. The thing is, when I press on the Button, nothing gets printed.
So, I don't know what exactly doesn't work. That's why I need the help of more experienced coders.

Comment: did it print  "addButtonTapped" or "subtractButtonTapped" log ?

Comment: Nothing gets printed

Comment: So it must be behind other elements. Try set color for it to debug. Or a better way is using Debug View Hierachy

Comment: I think  `awakeFromNib` won't get called because you are using `init(style:reuseIdentifier:)`  and there is no Nib file. So your piece of code which adds target to button won't run (`subtractButton.addTarget` and `addButton.addTarget`), so your buttons do nothing on tap. 

make a breakpoint in `awakeFromNib` function in order to make sure that it is being called, if not, so add the target of your button inside your initializer.

Comment: I set color and now see buttons background with the colors I set. I'm not sure how to use  Debug View Hierachy.

Comment: Mahsa Yousefi, you were correct, `awakeFromNib` is not get called, I transferred `addTarget` to `override init` section, but it still doesn't do anything.

Comment: The second problem with your code is that the frame of  `addAndSubtractView` is `(0,0,0,0)`. So any interaction with your buttons which are `addAndSubtractView`'s subviews is impossible. Within your constraint definition set valid frame size for this view so your problem will be solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copy your project and make my own. After debugging, i found this. The button in your view is not inside the view `addAndSubtractView`. So that means you can't click it. And your  `addAndSubtractView` does not show in the cell, It's hidden somewhere.

```
po addButton.frame
▿ (60.0, -17.0, 30.0, 34.0)
  ▿ origin : (60.0, -17.0)
    - x : 60.0
    - y : -17.0
  ▿ size : (30.0, 34.0)
    - width : 30.0
    - height : 34.0
```

Try fixing your auto-layout. I suggest you try SnapKit framework for better looking

Comment: Thanks man! I deleted `addAndSubtractView ` everything works now!